# Auto adjust screen brightness data

Tags: display, screen, data

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the data generated by the brightness sensor of the screen in a MacBook with this auto brigthness capabilities.

Do you know something how can we do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Amit Singh's [Experimenting With Light On Apple Notebook Computers](http://www.osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/light/) but note Apple do not provide official support for these methods:

> Please note that there are no Apple "APIs" to access the motion sensor or the ambient light sensor.

Amit's code examines the IOKit entry from `AppleLMUController`.

Also related to your question is [How do you programmatically access the ambient light sensor on Mac OS X 10.5+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625495/how-do-you-programmatically-access-the-ambient-light-sensor-on-mac-os-x-10-5)